# How to blocks user interaction with the underlying user interface while show loader in jquery?

Tags: javascript

Here's my loader is show in ajaxstart:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
                         $("#wait").css("display", "block");
                     });
                     $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
                         $("#wait").css("display", "none");
                     });
```

Css:

```
.wait {    
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1000;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;      
    top:20%;
    left:35%;
    padding:2px;    
}
```

my problem is that user can able to interact with background controls while show the loader.i don't want any user interaction with controls.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.wait != #wait` is the class or id?. change `$(".wait")` if is a classname

Comment: @prasad... thanks for the response.. i'm using like these  `<div id="wait" class="wait"><img src='../Styles/Images/Please Wait.gif' width="400" height="400" /></div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Css

```
.preloader-container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1031;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 25%;
}

.preloader-center {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
  top: 10%;
  left:30%;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 1000;
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

Javascript

```
function showLoader(container){
         var html = '<div class="preloader-container js-busy-loader"><div class="preloader-center"><img src="http://i49.tinypic.com/j5z8mb.gif"></div></div>';
                $(container).find(".js-ajax-loader,.js-busy-loader").remove();
                $(container).append(html);
    }

     function hideLoader(container){
            if(typeof container == 'string' && container!==''){
                $(container).find(".s-ajax-loader,.js-busy-loader").remove();
            }else{
                $("body").find(".s-ajax-loader,.js-busy-loader").remove();
            }
     }
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/h1wpmxs0/